# Access database does not update

Tags: vb.net

This is my current code, I'm just starting to code so I'm not really sure about the format of asking here so forgive me.

My problem is that every time I try to click update the "Record Successfully Updated" Message Box Would show up but the Data would not update. I am quite unsure of what to change since I'm pretty sure everything is correct already.
 I also tried adding an actual id number in the "' where CustomerID=" & myid & " " and it would update however I need it to be that it won't need it anymore.

*Excuse me if I didn't explain it quite well just tell me if there is something that needs explaining.*[Form]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jASEr.jpg

```
  Imports System.Data.OleDb

  Public Class Form3

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myid As Integer
    With DataGridView1
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            i = .CurrentRow.Index
            myid = .Rows(i).Cells("CustomerID").Value.ToString
            TextBox2.Text = .Rows(i).Cells("CustomerName").Value.ToString
            TextBox3.Text = .Rows(i).Cells("Address").Value.ToString
            TextBox4.Text = .Rows(i).Cells("Age").Value.ToString
            TextBox5.Text = .Rows(i).Cells("Gender").Value.ToString
            TextBox6.Text = .Rows(i).Cells("Birthday").Value.ToString
            TextBox7.Text = .Rows(i).Cells("CivilStatus").Value.ToString
            TextBox8.Text = .Rows(i).Cells("Religion").Value.ToString
            TextBox9.Text = .Rows(i).Cells("Citizenship").Value.ToString
            TextBox10.Text = .Rows(i).Cells("ContactNo").Value.ToString
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try
        Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim squery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim connStr As String
        Dim myid As Integer
        connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Desktop\temp2\Valenzuela10A\Valenzuela10A.mdb"
        conn.ConnectionString = connStr
        squery.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()
        squery.CommandText = "Update Customer set CustomerName='" & TextBox2.Text & "',Address='" & TextBox3.Text & "',Age='" & CInt(TextBox4.Text) & "',Gender='" & TextBox5.Text & "',Birthday='" & TextBox6.Text & "',CivilStatus='" & TextBox7.Text & "',Religion='" & TextBox8.Text & "',Citizenship='" & TextBox9.Text & "',ContactNo='" & TextBox10.Text & "' where CustomerID=" & myid & " "
        squery.ExecuteNonQuery()
        squery.Dispose()
        MsgBox("Record successfully updated.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Message")
        load_data()
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    load_data()
End Sub
Public Sub load_data()
    Try
        Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Desktop\temp2\Valenzuela10A\Valenzuela10A.mdb"
        conn.Open()
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Customer", conn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Start by learning the correct way to compose SQL using Parameters.  `Dim rows = squery.ExecuteNonQuery()` will tell you how many rows were afftected.  If it is non zero, it did update.  You also have some other things to Dispose there.  If you have a DGV and a DataSource you ought to consider letting NET do all that work for you.  Please read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a DataGrid to an Access table, do it this way..

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection
    Dim oledbAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim oledbCmdBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim changes As DataSet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sql As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Your mdb filename;"
        connection = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
        Sql = "select * from tblUsers"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            oledbAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, connection)
            oledbAdapter.Fill(ds)
            DataGridView1.Data Source= ds.Tables(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            oledbCmdBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(oledbAdapter)
            changes = ds.GetChanges()
            If changes IsNot Nothing Then
                oledbAdapter.Update(ds.Tables(0))
            End If
            ds.AcceptChanges()
            MsgBox("Save changes")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

http://vb.net-informations.com/dataadapter/dataadapter-datagridview-oledb.htm

There are several other ways to do this as well.  I'll leave it to you to explore other options.